# how to fix Images not showing in react app?

Tags: reactjs, image

in my case, .jpg images are showing but another format is not showing in my react application images are coming through CDN.

browser console print this :

[image]

[image]

What can affect this and how to solve this ?

Comment: Could you show the code where you are rendering your image

Comment: ` <div className="card-header__app-image">
                            <Img src={app.appDetails.logoImageFile}/>
                        </div>`